# chmod. Changing permission of file

Tags: file-permissions, sudo, chmod

I have remote server with Debian and I need to edit readonly file fcgid.conf on server. When I use sudo:

```
sudo su chmod 755 fcgid.conf
```

it responses:

```
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

Also I tried `cmod +x`:

```
chmod +x fcgid.conf
```

And got:

```
chmod: changing permissions of `fcgid.conf': Operation not permitted
```

Owner of file is **root** user and I don't know how to get permission to edit this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sudo` is not installed with Debian in the case you have defined a root password in the installation.

Either install `sudo` with

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install sudo
```

and make a `sudo` rule and add your user into the group:

```
$ adduser USERNAME sudo
$ visudo
```

enter:

```
%sudo ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

and then run again

```
$ sudo chmod +x fcgid.conf
```

see also here: [How to properly configure sudoers file, on debian wheezy?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86748/how-to-properly-configure-sudoers-file-on-debian-wheezy)
**or** you try

```
$ su root
```

and then

```
$ chmod +x fcgid.conf
```

Both methods provide that you know the root/admin password...

Comment: Using `sudo`, for now, is safe for you. Don't use `su`.

Comment: @VishalKumar What do you mean?

Comment: `sudo` is recommended way to access root user. `su` command changes to user to root and hence, is not recommended to new user.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355, Thanks a lot. I don't know root password, so now I will reset it.

Comment: @VishalKumar that is true, but if you don't have sudo and dont want to install it, its the only way to switch user to root.

Comment: @hasan OK let me know if you solved your problem or ask a further question here

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 thanks. Is there any way how I can reset password of root?

Comment: @hasan I advise you to try the method with sudo. I do not know how to change the root password on a remote server. Otherwise check here, but try to install `sudo` first like in the top of the post

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 But I cannot install sudo without knowing root password: 
`Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
`

Comment: @hasan I once has a Virtual Server where I had to reset the server because I couldnt get into the boot menue, but check here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10095/how-do-you-change-the-root-password-on-debian or https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Debian_reset_root_password